# JSON deserialize variable number of properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON class structure like this from a third party API (only the problem part shown):

```
"template": {
    "name": "MovieTemplate",
    "ruleName": "Movie Template",
    "zones": {
        "Products": {
            "type": "Record",
            "name": "Products",
            "content": "www.imagescloudsite.com/blahblah.gif"
            "records": [ … ]
        },
        "URL": {
            "type":"DVD",
            "name":"Bundle"
            "content": "www.imagescloudsite.com/blahblah.gif"
        }
    }
}
```

The "zones" property can contain many properties "**Products**","**URL**","Superman","Descartes",etc...

But, I do not know which ones and how many will be there, because these are added by our content guys in a special control panel. Newtonsoft Deserializer complains because I have a model like this and it clearly does not capture the zone name like 'Products' and 'URL':

```
public class Zone
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public List<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can capture the zone names using NewtonSoft?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your Zone property to a dictionary since you don't know the keys in before hand, but do know their content structure.

Like so

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you changed the Template class to the following:

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

You could then access the name via the key of the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use of dynamic would be a good bet

```
dynamic d = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");
```